# Hadoop FS delimieter

Tags: hadoop, filesystems

I'm attempting to copy a table to a file using hadoop fs -copyToLocal. The command works swimmingly, minus the fact that all my fields are merged together. Is there a way to specify a delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen exact same issues where coping Hive tables to local file system adds all the fields together in one giant line and '\n' character is not honored at the end of each row in table.

You best option is to use custom SerDe (Serializer and DeSerializer) to export hive to CVS as described [here](http://dev.bizo.com/2010/11/csv-and-hive.html). You can get the source code from [github](https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you copying from the Hive table? And
Are you copying directly from the warehouse directory? Please provide the full command that you are using.